# underscore 1.8.3 _.mapObject not working

Tags: underscore.js

I'm struggling to get this function to work and I'm continuing to get the following error:

TypeError: _.mapObject is not a function

I've tried the following:

- I've updated the underscore version to 1.8.3
- Ensured the other functions like _.map work okay
- I even checked the source code and I can see the _.mapObject function there as well.

I need this function because I want to modify object values to not include any nulls and instead have them replaced with empty strings.

Any suggestions are welcome

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What did you try? I seems working fine.

https://jsfiddle.net/ramseyfeng/3ru8e3e4/

```
var ac = _.mapObject({start: 5, end: 12}, function(val, key) {
  return val + 5;
});

alert(ac.start);
```